# How would I save my Custom View objects state to implement resume game?

Tags: android

I am making a game and I cant figure out how to save some information from my custom view object to keep state.
My game starts with a Title Screen Activity which brings up a custom view that launches the game screen activity.

```
if(playButtonPressed) {
    gameIntent = new Intent(myContext,GameActivity.class);
    myContext.startActivity(gameIntent);
}
```

The game screen also has a custom view, and I have setup the view to save the variables I need in GameView.onPause() and I can retrieve them from the GameActivity but how can I pass them to the TitleActivity to setup a resume game feature?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the options for storing data with Android at this link?

[Android - Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)